# Corrupted ints and sscanf -- and other C related memory issues

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, scanf

I've got a function `control()` which is threaded. It calls another function which parses some server responses. Here is some verbose initialization which doesn't take care of my problem.

```
    int oct1 = 0;
    int oct2 = 0;
    int oct3 = 0;
    int oct4 = 0;
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0;

    sscanf(passive_ip, "%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i", &oct1, &oct2, &oct3, &oct4, &p1, &p2);
```

I often find my results messed up. For example:

```
S->C: 227 Entering Passive Mode (128,111,40,221,206,170)
The Parsed Result: 128.111.40.221 206,170

S->C: 227 Entering Passive Mode (128,111,40,221,80,8)
The Parsed Result: 128.111.40.221 80,8170

S->C: 227 Entering Passive Mode (128,111,40,221,241,196)
The Parsed Result: 128.111.40.221 241,196

S->C: 227 Entering Passive Mode (128,111,40,221,70,216)
The Parsed Result: 128.111.40.221 70,2166
```

Notice how old values are appended / jumbled with new values. Any clue as to why this might happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are somehow forgetting to terminate `passive_ip`.  Whatever you're doing should be sure to end it with a terminating null byte.

Comment: @David, I think you're right. I'm realizing now passive_ip is a global variable, which means all threads are accessing it and updating it with their various port numbers. That must be part of the confusion there. Worse still, it's updated on a char-by-char basis (because the first time I wrote this I couldn't think of a better way to parse the IP :D). Terminating it would also help, as @rlibby suggests... but I think I'm going to just rewrite the parser to sscanf the IP and then remove the globalness from it all. I'll green-tick this soon if it works!